# Interchange product $\sigma$-algebra and countable intersection

Tags: measure-theory

If $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a decreasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras and $\mathcal G$ another $\sigma$-algebra, is it possible to interchange the intersection with the product $\sigma$-algebra?

$\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}(\mathcal F_n\otimes \mathcal G)=(\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}\mathcal F_n\otimes \mathcal G)$

If not, is there a condition for this equality?

Comment: What did you try? Which partial results can you prove?

Comment: $\supset$ is the easy one

Comment: You could include it in the OP. Also, I think you can remove the tag (stochastic-calculus).

Comment: sorry, I just found this

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92546/decreasing-sequence-of-product-sigma-algebras?rq=1

anyway, thx